# Azure Front Door - How to add geo filtering policy?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I want to apply a geo filter to azure front door for countries that are outside of the US.

I've applied a waf policy (following the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-tutorial-geo-filtering)), but I'm not getting the desired result. All traffic appears to be denied. If I try a different country code, all traffic seems to be allowed.

Here's an example of a deny policy I'm trying to get working. If I apply this rule and test via locabrowser, the traffic is allowed.

I'm testing this theory by using [locabrowser](https://locabrowser.com) to simulate traffic from different locations.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "frontdoorwebapplicationfirewallpolicies_DenyChinaWafPolicy_name": {
        "defaultValue": "DenyChinaWafPolicy",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/frontdoorwebapplicationfirewallpolicies",
        "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
        "name": "[parameters('frontdoorwebapplicationfirewallpolicies_DenyChinaWafPolicy_name')]",
        "location": "Global",
        "properties": {
            "policySettings": {
                "enabledState": "Enabled",
                "mode": "Prevention"
            },
            "customRules": {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "name": "geoFilterRule",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "ruleType": "MatchRule",
                        "rateLimitDurationInMinutes": 1,
                        "rateLimitThreshold": 0,
                        "matchConditions": [
                            {
                                "matchVariable": "RemoteAddr",
                                "operator": "GeoMatch",
                                "negateCondition": false,
                                "matchValue": [
                                    "CH"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "action": "Block"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "managedRules": {
                "ruleSets": []
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geo-filtering in AFD is currently broken. It includes all the country instead of specific location. Fix is made and will be released soon. Will update here once the fix is updated.

Comment: The fix have been deployed today. Are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: Thanks - I haven't tried yet.  I'll report back with status

Answer (score 1):

This also does not work for me. Whatever I set the action to **allow** or **block** with `matchVariable": "RemoteAddr"` and `"operator": "GeoMatch"`, It seems that this policy did not rely on the `"matchValue"`, just works depending on the action. It seems that Geo filtering with WAF is still not available.

Please note that [the Azure web application firewall (WAF) for Azure Front Door is currently in public preview.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/waf-overview)
[image]

You could give your voices or vote these [feedback1](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/37397986-azure-firewall-geo-based-rules) and [feedback2](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/34334419-geographic-filter-for-web-server) about geo-filtering.

Comment: Nancy, IP address filtering seems to work, so there is that. I may have overlooked it in the docs, but do you know if filtering a block of known IPs from a given location is possible?

Comment: I don't think IP address filtering is going to be very practical given a zone like the US has over 50k CIDR address ranges. Each IP filtering rule only allows 600 address matches. The amount of rules I'd have to create just to allow US only could get out of hand.

Comment: I don't think using IP address filtering per country or region is a good or possible way too. I suggest waiting for geo-filtering global available.